# Creating a standard chart using Custom SQL

Tags: sql

I am new SQL and attempting to create a 2D chart in Sparx EA by utilizing the Custom SQL function. My current code returns all functions in the model as a bar graph. I would like to be able to show the total number of functions that are related to a specific package. Is it possible to limit the search to a specific package instead of the entire model?

Current code that shows the total functions in the entire model:

```
SELECT t_object.Name, t_object.Stereotype AS Series

FROM t_object, t_package

WHERE t_object.Stereotype IN ('Function')
```

Comment: You need to join the tables together on some condition, right now it is a cartesian product of all t_object with all t_package

Comment: Sample data and desired results for these tables would help out a lot here.